# I need to trigger a script when a specific slide is shown (flexslider)

Tags: jquery, flexslider

In flexslider when a on specific slide (like just slide #2) i need to excecute some javascript when that slide is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use callback function of Flexslide, which fires after each slider animation completes.
Try to use setTimeout() function if your jQuery gets executed few micro-seconds before stable slide view.
https://woocommerce.com/flexslider/

after: function(){
}